# send ICMP ping from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ping, icmp

I'm not sure it's possible but thought I might be missing something.

I'm trying to send a ping request to a server that does not run HTTP-server from chrome extension.

### What I know so far:

So I can't initiate an HTTP request and measure the roundtrip, since there is no http server and the server cannot be modified.

chrome.socket - was a thing in Chrome-Packed-Apps, which is deprecated by now.

Any idea how to go about thins?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The only way is to write an additional utility that sends a ping, and invoke it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) API. Note that the documentation links to the wrong page about chrome apps so just ignore the warning there.

Comment: @wOxxOm so I can basically need to create electron-app that recive meassages from the extension and actually perform the ping (using chrome.socket or something) is that right?

Comment: You can use any language to write the utility.